# C++ Searching for a word in a CSV file

Tags: c++, csv, vector

I am trying to create a program that stores data from a CSV file and then searches it for key words.
I have this code, and there are no errors shown, but it wont run the program past asking for 'Enter word: '

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


int main(){

    vector<string> student(860);
    vector<string> question(860);
    vector<string> answer(860);

    int count = 0;
    string word;

    ifstream file("data2.csv");

    if (!file.is_open())
        cerr << "File not found" << endl;

    while (file.good()){

        for (int i = 0; i < 860; i++){

            getline(file, student[i], ',');
            getline(file, question[i], ',');
            getline(file, answer[i], ',');
        }
    }

    cout << "Enter word: ";
    cin >> word;

    for (int j = 0; j < 860; j++){
        if (answer[j].find(word) != std::string::npos){
            cout << student[j] << question[j] << answer[j] << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << count;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JakeFreeman it's not an infinite loop, he said it executes `Enter Word` !!. read my answer below

Comment: @organicoman Ok I misread the sentence deleted

Answer (score 0):

In order to get `std::cin` to contain the exact string (multiple words?) that the user inputs, you can use `std::getline()` which will support more than one word specified by the user. It's not clear from your problem statement if this is what you want or not.  Otherwise I don't see a problem with just using `std::cin` if all you're looking for is a single word of input.

```
std::string match;
std::cout << "Enter the exact string to search for: ";
std::getline(std::cin, match);
std::cout << "\nSearching for \"" << match << "\"" << std::endl;
```

Also, in your for loop for searching the answer strings, you should prefer to use the built in size of the vector you're looping through as opposed to a hard coded value.

```
for ( size_t j = 0; j < answer.size(); ++j )
{
    std::size_t found = answer[j].find(match);
    if (found != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "found \"" << match
            << "\" starting at character " << found << std::endl;
        count++;
    }
}
std::cout << "occurrences of match criteria: " << count << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks this was helpful! I'll implement it into my code

Answer (score 0):

the error is in `getline`, the first call to it, extracts the word until the comma the second call until the 2nd comma, the 3r call to third comma past the to the next new line (the next student's name).

So the next iteration in the `getline` call, will fetch the `question` as the `students` name then the `answer` as the `question` then the next `students` name as the `answer`, a total mess!!! ;) So you will never find the word you are looking for, thus no result. Get it?

to fix this, try to change the last `getline` to `getline(file, answer[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

So, I know this is not the best way to solve the problem. But, in a time crunch I was able to fix these few errors and add a system("pause"); at the end of my code so that it would let me see the results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


int main(){

    vector<string> student(860);
    vector<string> question(860);
    vector<string> answer(860);

    int count = 0;
    string word;

    ifstream file("data2.csv");

    if (!file.is_open())
        cerr << "File not found" << endl;

    while (file.good()){

        for (int i = 0; i < 860; i++){

            getline(file, student[i], ',');
            getline(file, question[i], ',');
            getline(file, answer[i], '\n');
        }
    }

    cout << "Enter word: ";
    cin >> word;

    for (int j = 0; j < 860; j++){
        if (answer[j].find(word) != std::string::npos){
            cout << student[j] << question[j] << answer[j] << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << count << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```